# input type="text" vs input type="search" in HTML5

Tags: forms, html, input

I'm new to HTML5 as begun to work with HTML5's new form input fields. When I'm working with form input fields, especially `<input type="text" />` and `<input type="search" />` IMO there wasn't any difference in all major browser including Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera. And the search field also behaves like a regular text field.

So, what is the difference between `input type="text"` and `input type="search"` in HTML5?

What is the real purpose of `<input type="search" />`?

Comment: http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-search.php

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Right now, there isn't a huge deal between them - maybe there never will be.
However, the point is to give the browser-makers the ability to do something special with it, if they want.

Think about `<input type="number">` on cellphones, bringing up number pads, or `type="email"` bringing up a special version of the keyboard, with @ and .com and the rest available.

On a cellphone, search could bring up an internal search applet, if they wanted.

On the other side, it helps current devs with css.

```
input[type=search]:after { content : url("magnifying-glass.gif"); }
```

Comment: +1 for two valid points,
1) `internal search applet for mobile phone`.
2)`ability to make better presentation`.
However, i supposed to wait to accept the answer, because i want to make sure there isn't any other purpose:)

Comment: Right now, there isn't.
The inputs are all either just names at the moment (like there is only partial support for input[type=color]), or the browsers have implemented their own special handling (like type=number or type=email or type=range).  There's no other option -- it's either got a special handling by the browser, or it doesn't.  Right now, in most browsers, type=search doesn't, and probably won't (except MAYBE making it look like a search box in iTunes or some other app).  Currently, it's there so that YOU can add extra functionality/presentation by knowing it's a search box.

Comment: One difference is that pressing [Esc] in a search input will clear the results. Super handy if your users are using it frequently.

Comment: @JoshH that *is* super-handy. Any idea which browsers (and versions) that affects, currently? I'd totally be willing to update the answer and bring it up to the current(/future) state of the evergreens, given that the landscape is very different now, than it was a year and a half ago.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using pseudo-elements on replaced elements: [it's against standards](http://red-team-design.com/css-generated-content-replaced-elements/), though works in some cases.

Comment: @PaulKozlovitch beside, last time I checked it doesn't work with inputs

Answer (score 37):

Visually/functionally, 2 differences if the input type is '**search**':-

1. You get a '**X**' symbol at the end of the input/search box to clear texts in the box
2. Pressing '**Esc**' key on keyboard also clears texts

Comment: This most certainly does not happen everywhere. In which environment is this observed?

Comment: "X" icon was visible in edge

Comment: Edge and Chrome

Comment: This is not universal, it is up to the user agent. Chromium based browsers will append the "X" icon and hitting the escape key will clear the text, but this would not happen on FireFox (as of writing this).

Answer (score 32):

> It does absolutely nothing in most browsers. It just behaves like a
>   text input. This isn't a problem. The spec doesn't require it to do
>   anything special. WebKit browsers do treat it a bit differently
>   though, primarily with styling.
>
> A search input in WebKit by default has an inset border, rounded
>   corners, and strict typographic control.

Also,

> This isn't documented anywhere that I know of nor is it in the spec,
>   but you if you add a results parameter on the input, WebKit will apply
>   a little magnifying glass with a dropdown arrow showing previous
>   results.

```
<input type=search results=5 name=s>
```

[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/)

Above all, it provides a semantic meaning to the `input type`.

**Update:**

[Chrome 51 removed support for the results attribute:](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/chrome-53-deprecations#remove-results-attribute-for-input-typesearch)

Answer (score 7):

On some browsers, it also supports the "results" and "autosave" attributes which provides automatic "recent searches" functionality with the magnifier icon.

[More info](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/5-search.html)

Comment: Chrome 51 removed support for the `results` attribute: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/chrome-53-deprecations#remove-results-attribute-for-input-typesearch

Answer (score 2):

Actually be very careful about assuming it does nothing. When you go to style inputs with the type search they have certain attributes that cannot be changed. Try to change the border on one and you will find it quite impossible. There are several other disallowed CSS attributes, check out [this](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/) for all the details.

Also as mentioned by Jashwant there's the result attribute, though it doesn't work very well unless you also include the autosave attribute. The drop down will not work in most browsers, however, so use at your own peril.

Answer (score 2):

There's browser difference in action, when you type some words then keyed ESC in input `type="search"` in chrome/safari the input box will get cleared. but in `type="text"` scenario, the words will not get cleared. So be careful choosing the type especially when u use it for autocomplete or search related feature

Answer (score 1):

Bonus point: `input type="search`" has the ability to use the `onsearch` attribute (although I have noticed this does NOT work in Microsofts new Edge Browser), which eliminates the need to write a custom `onkeypress=if(key=13) { function() }` thing.

Answer (score 1):

using input type="search" make the keybord enterkey's text show "search", which may improve user experience. however, you have to adjust the style if using this type.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the programmers point of view, a programmer can easily determine the purpose of the input by looking on the type and it's easy for CSS styling and for JavaScript or JQuery to verify rule in the inputs.

Answer (score -2):

But it has a bad affect on yout input element, if you set

```
<input type="search">
```

And in your css you set

```
input {background: url("images/search_bg.gif");}
```

It wont showup at all.