# Making use of all input types

Tags: html, hyperlink

I've been developing for some time now...every now and then I find out about more HTML tags, PHP functions etc that I never new I had at my disposal.

Today, I'm talking about the different HTML input types....well, only one and then some link->rel values...

Input type: search?

I have looked in several places and all I get is the obvious answer of what it's purpose is.
I can do fulltext queries just fine by making the field a text type...

so what's the technical difference between the text and search input types? and are there any benefits of using making the input field a search type?

And, I have similar misunderstandings with some of the rel values of the link tag:

Next, prev, search etc...

I can do the same things without using those rels...I can create a 'slideshow' of articles without using next/prev. search, i don't understand at all... I can only find the defeintion of it..'Links to a search tool for the document'...does this mean a tool like that which google provides so your users can search through a document?

I can do these things without using s altogether so I'm guessing the answer to my question is in the fact that I don't use  for these tasks and maybe I should? Combine then with AJAX?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589770/input-type-text-vs-input-type-search-in-html5

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there are no differences between `input type='search'` and `input type='text'`. The reason these new HTML input types are put in place is so that functionality can be added later in the future. It's good practice to use `type='search'` when you are creating a search field, as it could become more useful in the future and it also makes your code more semantic.

Answer (score 1):

There are really some differences are there between "search" and "text"

- These two are rendered differently according to the browser. safari, Chrome like browsers adds a [cross icon](http://html5doctor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/figure_6-6.png) to clear the field more quickly than normal text field.
- And in smartphones it changes the normal return button of the soft keyboard into [magnifier or search button](http://html5doctor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/figure_6-7.png). which is more user friendly
- some browsers will trigger certain applets while user is on a search field

Answer (score -1):

HTML 5 defines a lot of new input types such as `date`, `time`, `number`, `email`, ... (you find a complete list [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)) which can be used by modern browsers to provide more functionality such as validation or support for input.

The browser can display a calendar for `date` inputs. On a touchscreen a different keyboard (containing @) is shown for an input field of type `email` or `phone`. For the `search` attribute an hourglass might be shown.

You should always use the new input types, as they provide more semantic information. An old browser will interpret them as `<input type="text" />`. A disadvantage is that different browsers display the same field differently and some browsers do not use the tags at all. For input type `search` a magnifier might be displayed.

Your second question is about [link types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-links). Again, this is semantic information mainly for search engines or user agents. The different link types might be displayed in a separate navigation bar.